# Instancing the original asset in the scene after modifying it

Tags: asset-browser, asset

I have done some assets for my project but i want to modify some assets without destroying the original source,[image]

as you can see this is my asset, I left clicked on the viewport to make sure the asset is not selected in the asset browser, and then tried to do a random modifaction to it, however when I put an another one the deformation applied to it too.[image]
what should I do?

Comment: If you want your object to have a different mesh you need to choose Append and not Append (Reuse Data). Also if you use Append (Reuse Data) and change the mesh it will change the mesh of the original and therefore also change the next you'll drop into the scene (it won't change the original if it comes from the User Library though)

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior when you drag an asset in the scene is to *Append (Reuse Data)*. It will look for instances of the asset in the scene and re-use it if it exists. That way if you append a material x times for instance, it automatically recognizes that you appended the same asset and does not create duplicate data blocks.

If you want to force instancing the asset with the original data, you need to set the behavior to just *Append*.

[image]